# GCC installed on ubuntu 14.04, but no toolchain visible on eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, gcc

So itś my first time using eclipse in ubuntu and I seem to have problems with setting up GCC as the toolchain. I expect the toolchains to work with a standard HelloWorld example, but they don't (after building the project of course).

I get the following error:

[image]

When adding the new project, I only have a choice between these toolchains:

[image]

When unmarking **¨Show project types and toolchains only if...¨**, I do get the GCC toolchain in the list, but that doesn´t seem right (and is also not working).

Comment: You're using Cross Compiler, I guess for ARM: did you set it up?

Comment: Actually, I use Linux GCC. I don't want to use Cross GCC, but MinGW or Cygwin GCC.

Comment: In posted image cross compiler is selected. I thought you selected as shown

Comment: I tried with both of them, but thats not the problem. The problem is that I cant run the application, even after it seems building. How can I install a compatible toolchain?